# Objective-C - How to convert a uchar to a string of bits

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bit-manipulation

I have a scenario where I have a `uchar` variable and I need to get its representative `bits` (in any form: string, bit array, array of bools, array of `1` and `0` ints, anything).

I've been searching for how to do this in `Objective-C` all morning with no luck.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9603323/1091539

Comment: Look up "convert to binary" in C, you should be able to find lots of implementations.

Comment: There, it's done.  A uchar is a binary number, and a binary number is an array of bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uchar getBit(uchar value, int bitIndex)
{
    return value & (1<<bitIndex);
}

NSString *bitsFromUchar(uchar value)
{
    NSMutableString *bits = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        [bits appendString:(getBit(value, i)?@"1":@"0")];
    }
    return bits;
}
```